# Dropbox fails with "Dropbox requires administrator rights to continue, but could not elevate (unexpected error 6)" during installation

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, administrator, uac

I just tried to install Dropbox on a users Windows 7 64 bit machine at work...and the installation program asked for my administrator password.  When I type it in I get the error:

> "Dropbox requires administrator rights to continue, but could not
>   elevate (unexpected error 6)"

and the program exits.

I tried holding down shift and running it as administrator and the same thing happens.

I also installed it by logging out of the users account and logging back in as the administrator.  This succeeds, but, when I log back in as the user I cannot open dropbox.

Lastly, I installed the program as the user, instead of as domain administrator, and the program installed but reported that some features of dropbox would be unavailable because of the lack of administrator privileges.

The user started using it, and it appears to work, but I'm concerned about what features of dropbox won't work later, which is why I'm asking what the error message means, how to fix it and what the implications of not installing it successfully as administrator are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post from some years back says the lost features are context menu integration and icon overlays:

https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=10563